# an "average" home with computation

Tags: meaning

An [ielts post](https://www.ielts-exam.net/academic_writing_samples_task_1/672/) says

> The graph below shows the demand for electricity in England during typical days in winter and summer. The pie chart shows how electricity is used in an **average** English home.

[image]

What does "an **average** English home" mean here?

I understand the meaning of average

> Meaning_1: the result you get by adding two or more amounts together and dividing the total by the number of amounts
>
> Meaning_2: a standard or level that is considered to be typical or usual

Generally, "an average English home" might be similar to "a standard English home". However, this involves some extra math.

Should I go with Meaning_1 or Meaning_2? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"a standard home" is an average home, meaning how most people in that particular country live. For example: two adults and their two children live in a house that is of a certain size and they use a certain amount of water, electricity and gas per day. Of course, this differs from country to country. If you compare an average home in Japan to one in the United States you will find "average" can be very different, depending on the number of people living in a house, the size of the house, age, how they spend their day, etc. So go with nr.2

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to look at exactly how the people who created those graphs compiled the numbers. It's impossible to say without looking at the details of this particular study.

They MIGHT have defined an "average" home as a "typical" home. But what is a "typical" home? There's no objectively correct, absolute definition. Like, they might have looked at statistics on the size of homes in England, number of family members, etc, and then made some general, intuitive statement like, "it looks like the typical home is 1500 square feet and has 3 people living in it" or whatever numbers. Or they might have calculated the average size of all homes. Or they might have taken the median size. Or who knows? Whatever they considered typical, they would then have to decide what the range was to be included in typical homes. Like if the average was (again, just making up a number) 1500 square feet, is "typical" betwwen 1300 and 1700? Between 1200 and 1800? Or what?

They might have found the energy consumption for all homes and then averaged it together. I'd think that would be the most sensible thing to do, but whether the people who did this study thought so or not I have no way of knowing.

Just by the way, it's ambiguities like this that make it possible for people to play games with statistics. I'm not saying this particular study is manipulating statistics, but there are lots of studies that do, especially when the people who funded the study want a particular result.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. "You'd have to look at exactly how the people who created those graphs compiled the numbers", I totally agree with you! The question is how do I do that with that particular graph. The [link](https://www.ielts-exam.net/academic_writing_samples_task_1/672/) at the beginning of OP is all I have. Would you please give a hint on this particular situation.

Comment: As far as I can see, they don't provide a link to a detailed report of the study. So the short answer is: There's no easy way to know. I used to be involved in politics and people would often publish studies claiming to prove some controversial claim, and sometimes I would dig into the studies looking for details. Often you can't tell from brief summaries or news reports -- they just don't say. As this appears to be an exercise for some class, the point probably isn't to really "prove" anything, but just to give the student some graphs and statistics and see if he can make sense of them.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, that's very kind of you! Would you please give a similar graph that does provide a link to a detailed report of the study, so that I can follow your suggestion to understand how those people compiled the numbers?